# How to set value with button to input text in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have input text:

```
        <div><label wicket:for="name">Name</label><input type="text" wicket:id="name" /></div>
```

Now I need to add two buttons which just add to this input text some value. How can I implements this ?

with this buttons I dont want do send form just edit value in input rext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to send the whole form. You could use an AjaxButton with an onClick-method changing the model of your input field and adding the field to the AjaxRequestTarget. Anything not involving a server roundtrip at least by Ajax would be hard  to do using wicket methods since wicket runs on the server. Of course you could do this by JavaScript but that wouldn't involve wicket.

Comment: "Of course you could do this by JavaScript but that wouldn't involve wicket." Which is perfectly acceptable in some cases.

Comment: @biziclop I know but since the OP asked specifically how to do it in wicket and tagged the question as 'wicket', I thought it would be nice to provide him with a wicket-answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I just know that some people working with Wicket go to great lengths and introduce awful hacks just to avoid having to write two lines of JS. You should always be aware of this balancing act. (Not you personally, I meant in general.)

Comment: @biziclop Granted but I don't think this applies here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input type="button">Click Me</input>`.

and at `onclick` event of these buttons call a javascript function which will edit the input text.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Wicket, this is just plain Javascript.
You can do something like this

```
<div>
 <label wicket:for="name">Name</label>
 <input type="text" wicket:id="name" id="markupId"/>
 <input type="button" value="Do something" onclick="javascript:editField();"/>
</div>
```

With the following Javascript somewhere in your page (or in loaded script files):

```
function editField(){
  document.getElementById("markupId").value = "My value";
}
```

If you use a Javascript framework like `JQuery`, you should bind the function to the onclick event using your framework (prevents polluting HTML with your javascript)